# Hackerrank Staircase in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem) problem in C++ using `std::cout` and using `setw` and `setfill`

my original code was this:

```
void staircase(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(n-(i+1));
        cout << setfill('#') << setw(i+1) << '#'<< endl;
    }
}
```

This doesn't print out the spaces that right aligns the `#` character. I added this to the output buffer `cout << setfill(' ') << setw(n-(i+1)) << ' ';` and it prints the space character, but for the last line it prints a space character.

Is there something in `setw` that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to print out something or the second `setfill` and `setw` replace the first. eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void staircase(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(n-(i+1)) << '|';
        cout << setfill('#') << setw(i+1) << '#'<< endl;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    staircase(4);
}
```

prints out

```
  |#
 |##
|###
|####
```

All you need to do is print out something more useful than |, like a #, and fix up your alignment math.

Answer (score -1):

A good solution for this problem is to use default constructor of string class like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
        int j = i+1;
        string spaces(n-j, ' ');
        string hashes(j, '#');
        cout << spaces + hashes << endl;

}
```